# Selecting child element in ObservableArray based on id of current foreach element

Tags: knockout.js

So the situation is as following:
I got my menu items (and child menu items) in an ObservableArray (and child items in a child ObservableArray). I dynamically add child elements in the ObservableArray and now i'm trying to dynamically display div's based on the child elements. As you can see below the `ChildObservableArray` also contains the `destUrl`, and I'm trying to select the menuitem basic on `BananaID` (which is basically the same as the current index, but index didn't seem to work either) but it gives the error

`"Uncaught Error: Unable to parse bindings.
Message: TypeError: Cannot read property 'ChildObservableArray' of undefined;".`

```
<section data-bind="foreach: viewModel.Bananas"> 
    <div data-bind="attr: { 'id': viewModel.ObservableArray()[0].ChildObservableArray()[BananaID].destUrl }">
    </div>
</section>
```

It does however work if i replace `BananaID` with any number (but just for 1 menu item), i think its looking for `BananaID` in the `ChildObservableArray` instead of the current `viewModel.Bananas`.

edit:
Here is the Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Dennis50/PhxSe/1/

Comment: Can you post your view model? and fiddle if possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your fiddle, (which at the time of writing this contained some errors) [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/origineil/PhxSe/2/) does what you desire.

### Considerations

- You  use `viewmodel` to reference your viewmodel in the bindings. You don't need that. `ko.applyBindings(viewModel)` does that for you.
- Inside of the `foreach`, `$root` is the reference to the viewmodel.

---

If those usages are there due to this being part of a larger model structure, then you would need to modify the accessors accordingly.

If `BananaID()` didn't solve your problem (+1 to  GôTô), something else is going on. Aside from cleaning up the model references, adding some new visualization elements, and fixing the javascript declarations, that is pretty much all I modified from the original fiddle.

Answer (score 1):

If BananaID is an observable, try with `BananaID`**()**

Comment: BananaID is indeed an observable, however this still returns the same error. Also i can show the BananaID using text: BananaID, but when i put it in the '[]' brackets it returns the error.

Comment: Oh, sorry, the error is with viewModel.ObservableArray()[0]. Is `ChildObservabelArray()` an element of viewModel.Bananas[0]? If so just remove viewModel.ObservableArray()[0] and put ChildObservableArray()[BananaID()].destUrl

Comment: If you could post your (or part of your) viewmodel, that's help

Comment: ChildObservableArray is an observableArray inside the observableArray 'ObservableArray' and viewModel.Bananas is a list of Bananas which all have an unique BananaID (This BananaID is similar the position of the ChildObservableArray which i need to get the destUrl from). edit: I will post the viewModel asap.

Comment: Just post your abbreviated viewmodel we are shooting in the dark here.

Comment: Added a Fiddle to the main post.